# Get addressbook all phone labels list

Tags: ios6, abaddressbook

I need to get addressbook all phone labels.

I mean, not phone labels for all existing contacts, but all phone labels list(when you touch phone label in Contacts app there is a list of labels).

[image]

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own labels on demand for individual ABPerson records. There is no central place where iOS keeps a list of all the standard labels. Here's my list of the iOS constants (I might have missed some) that are mapped to strings via `ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel`:

```
kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel 
kABPersonPhoneIPhoneLabel 
kABPersonPhoneMainLabel   
kABPersonPhoneHomeFAXLabel
kABPersonPhoneWorkFAXLabel
kABPersonPhonePagerLabel  
kABWorkLabel              
kABHomeLabel              
kABOtherLabel
```

Any label that you add yourself will not be localized by iOS, it will appear verbatim regardless of locale setting.